# Flexible Error Message using Modal in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery to validate fields (text, email fields), whenever requirements are not met such as invalid email address or empty / unfilled text fields, a pop up message is being shown

here's the code

```
//validation
    $("#RoleConfigForm").validate({
        rules: {

            "group_code[]": {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 25,
            },
            "role_name[]": {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 25,
            },

            "email_address[]": {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 30,
                email: true,
            },
        },
        onkeyup: false,
        errorClass: "invalid",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $('#ResultDialog p').html("@hmis_resources.Message.msg_empty_fields");
            $('#ResultDialog').modal();
        }, 
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            ajaxFormSubmit();
        }
    });
```

the responsible for it is the errorPlacement part, however it's error message is generic, I want to make it flexible depending on the error (invalid email, empty)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery Validation documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#messages), you can use use the `messages` option to set custom messages per field:

```
$("#RoleConfigForm").validate({
  rules: {
    "group_code[]": {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 25,
    }
  },
  messages: {
    "group_code[]": {
      required: "A group code is required.",
      maxlength: "@hmis_resources.Message.msg_empty_fields"
    },
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: i did this, but it is not displaying in Modal, the way it originally was, is there way to use the message and still put it on modal? like the one i initially did?

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, you could just use your existing code, but set `$('#ResultDialog p').html(error)`, where the error is the custom message you set.

Comment: can you give examples

Comment: the error messages are coming from a resources and not manually written, like this ("@hmis_resources.Message.msg_empty_fields"); is it possible to include that in message?

Comment: You should just be able to set those in the messages option. Updated example to demonstrate.

Comment: I follow your recommendation i just dont know, it keeps on showing the initial string input, even though is is already replaced by  "@hmis_resources.Message.msg_empty_fields", i already removed or clear cache, still the same

Comment: I tried using this  jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        required: "@hmis_resources.Message.msg_empty_fields",
        email: "@hmis_resources.Message.msg_invalid_email"
    });
and it is now working, however it is including a red border as defined by errorClass: "invalid", how can I removed it in the modal, since it should only be included in the textbox